# retract in an abstract category.

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Suppose I have a category $C$ and a morphism $f: a\rightarrow b$ in this category. Suppose that the induced map $f^{\ast}:Hom_{C}(a,a)\rightarrow Hom_{C}(b,a)$ induces a bijection of sets. Is it true that there exists a morphism $g:b\rightarrow a$ such that $g\circ f=id_{a}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have a mistake and Hom(b,a) should be Hom(a,b).

If that is what you meant, then the answer is no.

For a simple example, take a category with two objects `a,b` and a single non-identity arrow `f : a -> b`. Then `Hom(a,a) = {id_a}` and `Hom(a,b) = {f}` and `f` indeed induces a bijection by composition `g |-> f o g`.

This is similar to some basic facts in topology, for instance not every surjective continuous function has a continuous inverse.

However, if you ask for `f` to give not just a bijection on `Hom(a,a) -> Hom(a,b)` but instead give a bijection `Hom(c,a) -> Hom(c,b)` for *every* `c`, naturally, then you do get an inverse morphism, as a consequence of the Yoneda lemma and the fact that a natural transformation has a natural inverse iff each of its components has an inverse.